# How to solve two conflicting namespaces with the same name

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have in my own code an namespace *core* that is conflicting with the namespace *core* of a dynamic library that I am using. The problem appears because I can not modify neither one nor the other. The first *core* because is part of our team project, and the second because is part of the library. Is there a way to solve this situation?

Comment: What is conflict? Are you use using namespace?

Comment: I think @WendiKidd is right. I know you don't want to rename them, but "core" is just not a good namespace name.

Comment: The fact is that I *can't* rename them. It is not in my hands. And both our project and the library are silly enough to not put anything on top, like myproject::core

Comment: So, there is no suitable solution for this in this case i think.

Comment: What is the actual conflict you're getting? Since you can't rename either namespace you have to look at the details of the exact conflict to fix it. Perhaps there's some using directive that you can change or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try turning your core namespace into a sub namespace.

This way you can get access to each 'core' namespace. This also explicitly shows which 'core' is being referred to. Even if the external library has the same function names you will be safe.

However, you mentioned that you can't actually change anything in the original code, so your only option is to use a different library and hope it doesn't have a 'core' namespace in it. Seems to me like it might be alot easier to convince your team to change their code.

```
// Your 'core' namespace, inside your own namespace.
namespace Mygame
{
  namespace core
  {
    void Foo();
  }
}

// Access both namespaces safely.
Mygame::core::Foo();
core::Foo();
```

Comment: This answer is perfectly valid. Can someone please explain why this has been down voted? This is the whole point of namespaces, and nesting them is recommended to AVOID situations like this. The question itself is flawed, "how do I fix something I have no control over"

Comment: The OP explicitly said that he didn't want this solution. He wanted magic. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to change the name of the namespace you have access to.  Situations like this are why it's a good idea to give things you create (classes, libraries, namespaces...) a prefix that sets them apart from other items which might use similar names.

For example, if I have a game manager, I won't just call the class `Manager`.   I'll call it `MygameGameManager` or something similar, to distinguish it from other classes--ie. if someone comes along later and adds a `SoundManager` to the project.  It's important to find a balance in naming conventions between making things clear and distinct, and being too verbose in naming.  The balance is out there, you just have to find it!

Comment: Or instead of ridiculously long class names, you could just wrap your code with your own namespace, 'Mygame', perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
namespace core {
    // define namespace members
}
```

to

```
namespace myproject_core {} // namespace "declaration"
using namespace core = myproject_core; // "namespace alias"

// core:: refers only to your code now

namespace myproject_core {
    // define namespace members
}
```

Now the linker will see no conflict, and your code won't see the name change.

---

> The problem appears because I can not modify neither one nor the other.

Well, if you can't modify *anything* then there is no solution. I've made an assumption in this answer, but maybe you can clarify what sort of change would be acceptable?